# parallelizing (openmp) a function call causes memory error

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm calling a class function in parallel using OpenMP. It's working okay in serial or putting the **my_func** part in the critical section (slow apparently). Running in parallel, however, keeps giving the following error message,

> malloc: *** error for object 0x7f961dcef750: pointer being freed was
> not allocated

I think the problem is with the **new** operators in the **my_func**, i.e., The pointer **myDyna** seems to be shared among threads.  My questions are,

1)Isn't anything inside the parallel region **private**, including all the pointers in the **my_func**? Meaning that, each thread should have its own copy of **myDyna**, but why the error occurred?

2)Without changing the **my_func** too much, what can be done to make the parallelization work at the **main** level? For example, would it work by adding a copy constructor in the **myDyna**?

```
 void my_func(){

    Variables *theVars = new Variables();

    //trDynaPS Constructor for the class.
    trDynaPS *myDyna = new trDynaPS(theVars, starttime, stepsize, stoptime);

    ResultRate = myDyna->trDynaPS_Drive(1, 1);

    if (theVars != nullptr) {
        myDyna->theVars = nullptr;
        delete theVars;
    }
    delete myDyna;
};

int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    {
       for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        //I have multiple copies of myclass as a vector
            myclass[i]->run(); //my_func is in the run operation
       }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is in `my_func`? It looks ok. Try running the program in a memory debugger like `valgrind` to check where the error really is.

Comment: That example would not compile, since there is no declaration of `ResultRate`. *Assuming* it is global there is clearly a race here...

Comment: The ResultRate is just a vector of double, results from calling the trDynaPS_Drive function. I will make up a simple version as a runnable example. I get your point. Multiple threads are writing to the same ResultRate. But since this is a ''void'' function with no return value, can this still cause the error? @JimCownie

Comment: The context in which a race happens doesn't affect whether it is a race or not.  If `ResultRate` is shared, then you're only getting the result from a single thread being used in all of them, and, if they all try to `delete[]` that later you'll certainly get a crash. But, this snippet is so small we're completely guessing...